# Vote Breakdown on mobile application?

Tags: support, ios-app, vote-count

One thing I like being able to see is the split-vote-count of questions and answers to determine if they're controversial whenever I'm deciding best practices. However, this feature isn't implemented on the mobile application yet. Are there any plans to include this in a future update?

Comment: It is.  Long-press on the score to see a toast of it.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was a long-press. I thought you just had to touch it like a click. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Makoto While I'm at it, is there a way to see the amount of views for a post from the mobile app?

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Makoto in the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314585/vote-breakdown-on-mobile-application#comment293729_314585), you can long-press the score to make the breakdown visible:

[image]